# ¿cómo hacer que una variable aumente en cada iteración de un algoritmo recursivo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import numpy as np
def recorre_array(a, init_pos=0 ):
  for i in a:
    if type(i) == np.ndarray:
      recorre_array(i, init_pos)
    else:
      i=init_pos
      print(i)
    init_pos+=1

x=np.zeros([3,2,2,4])
recorre_array(x)
```

la idea es que recorra recursivamente el array 4D de ceros y asigne numeros consecutivos empezando en "init_pos" al recorrerla

Comment: Hola Sebatian, ¿a que te refieres con asignar exactamente? En tu función solo imprimes,  lo digo porque es muy posible que se pueda hacer lo que deseas de forma más eficiente y simple con NumPy en vez de usar una función recursiva. ¿La idea sería numerar cada item de forma recursiva, por ejemplo, para (3D) `[[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]` tendríamos algo como `[[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], [[6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]]`?

Comment: Dado:
una especificación de dimensiones de un array (d0,d1,...dn−1) de n dimensiones y una permutación de dichos elementos del 0 a n−1;
una dirección de memoria de base (de inicio);
un tamaño de dato.
Obtén la matriz de posiciones de memoria de cualquier array numpy de tales dimensiones.
Por ejemplo:
dims = [2,3,4]
order = [2,1,0]
la salida ha de ser
`[[[ 0  4  8 12]
  [16 20 24 28]
  [32 36 40 44]]
 
 [[48 52 56 60]
  [64 68 72 76]
  [80 84 88 92]]]`
Lo priemro que supuse debpia hacer era una matriz enumerada como la del ejemplo que pusiste

Answer (score 0):

Para ejecutar metodos recursivos siempre es recomendable utilizar dichos metodos dentro de una clase, pues si los pones dentro de una clase no importa el orden en que se ejecute el script siempre se podra acceder a los metodos o variables  a través del `self`.

Para solucionar este problema cree una clase y en su constructor ejecute el metodo `recorre_array`; cree tambien una variable local de la clase llamada `contador` a la cual le voy sumando uno a uno las veces que se ejecuta el metodo.

Finalmente lo metodo dentro de un `if __name__ == "__main__":` para que se ejecute este script como script principal, pero si estas trabajando con jupyter no hace falta, podrias solo quitarlo y ajustar su indentacion.

El script completo es:

```
import numpy as np

class Recursiva:
    contador = 0

    def __init__(self):
        x = np.zeros([3,2,2,4])
        self.recorre_array(x)

    def recorre_array(self, a, init_pos=0 ):
        for i in a:
            if type(i) == np.ndarray:
                self.recorre_array(i, init_pos)
            else:
                i=init_pos
                print(i)
                init_pos+=1
        self.contador += 1
        print('La cuenta va en %i' % self.contador)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Se ejecuto el metodo recursivo %i veces' % Recursiva().contador)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para generar un array enumerado (poblado con enteros de forma secuencial) de dimensiones arbitrarias no precisas de una función recursiva, basta con usar `np.arange` para generar el rango y luego simplemente aplicar `np.reshape` sobre el mismo para pasar del array 2D al array nD:

```
dims = (2, 3, 4)
arr = np.arange(np.prod(dims)).reshape(dims)
```

> ```
> >>> arr
> array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
>         [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
>         [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],
>
>        [[12, 13, 14, 15],
>         [16, 17, 18, 19],
>         [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
> ```